# Special character (&) in the folder name causing issues - command line

Tags: command-line, path, cmd

I have a folder with name "R&D" in D drive.
when I run a command in windows command prompt as

> D:\> cd R&D

I got the exception as below

> the system cannot find path specified.
>   'D' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Please help me on this

Comment: Try double-quoting the folder name.

Comment: `cd "R&D"` works for me.

Comment: yes its working with double-quoiting.. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , It's working with double-quoiting

> D:\> cd "R&D"

thanks, Lee and Austin

Comment: the answer from Lee and Austin